# Возможно ли с помощью callback функций менять запрос к БД? Python DASH

Tags: python, flask, dash

Есть следующий код:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,  external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
reg = '\d{4,}' 
sql = f"""
WITH 
logs AS (
SELECT 
     EXTRACT( UTMCampaign, '{reg}') c_id,
 sum(countEqual(goalsID, 237757866)) cb,
 sum(countEqual(goalsID, 237770052)) cb_roistat,
 sum(countEqual(goalsID, 237843834)) all_forms
FROM unistroy.logs_visits_88839580
--WHERE UTMContent LIKE '%desktop%'
--WHERE UTMContent LIKE '%mobile%' or UTMContent LIKE '%tablet%'
  WHERE Date BETWEEN '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
GROUP BY UTMCampaign
 ),

 yd as (
   SELECT 
   Date,
   sum(Clicks) Clc,
   sum(Impressions) Imp,
   round(sum(Cost), 2) Costs,
   CampaignName,
   CAST (CampaignId as varchar ) CampaignId 
   FROM unistroy.unojktopYD
   --WHERE Device = 'DESKTOP' 
   --WHERE Device = 'MOBILE' or Device = 'TABLET'
   GROUP BY Date, CampaignName, CampaignId, Device
   ),

  calls AS 
  (SELECT EXTRACT( visit_utm_campaign, '{reg}') cid,
    count(id) call

  FROM unistroy.calls_df
 --WHERE visit_utm_content LIKE '%desktop%'
 --WHERE visit_utm_content LIKE '%mobile%' or visit_utm_content LIKE '%tablet%'
 WHERE date BETWEEN '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
 GROUP BY cid )
  SELECT   yd.CampaignId CampaignId,
     yd.CampaignName CampaignName,
     sum(Clc) Clicks,
     sum(Imp ) Impressions,
     round(sum(Costs),2) Cost,
     logs.cb_roistat roi_call ,
     logs.all_forms forms ,
     calls.call ph_call,
     roi_call + forms + ph_call Leads_Total,
     round(((Leads_Total)/Clicks) * 100.0, 2) CR,
     round(Cost/(Leads_Total),2) CPL,
     round(Cost/Clicks, 2) CPC
     
     
     FROM yd 
    LEFT JOIN logs  ON yd.CampaignId = logs.c_id 
    LEFT JOIN  calls  ON yd.CampaignId = calls.cid
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '{start_date}' and '{end_date}' and CampaignId !='' 
    GROUP BY CampaignId, CampaignName,  roi_call, forms, ph_call 
    """
    df = client.query_dataframe(sql)

    # дополнительная предобработка
    #...


    trace = go.Bar(x=df.CampaignName, y=df.CPL, name='CPL')
    calls_trace = go.Bar(x=df.CampaignName, y=df['Leads_Total'], name='Calls')
    cost_trace = go.Bar(x=df.CampaignName, y=df.Cost, name='Cost')
    app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1("Unistroy Dash", style={'textAlign': 'center'}),

    html.P(x, style={'textAlign': 'left'}),
    html.Div(children=[
    
    html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Graph(
            id='cpl-graph',
            figure={
            'data': [trace],
            'layout':
            go.Layout(title='CPL', barmode='stack')
            })
        ]),

    html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Graph(
                id='calls-graph',
                figure={
                'data': [calls_trace],
                'layout':
                go.Layout(title='Leads_Total', barmode='stack')
                })
        ]),
    html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Graph(
                id='cost-graph',
                figure={
                'data': [cost_trace],
                'layout':
                go.Layout(title='Cost', barmode='stack')
                })
        ]),
    ], style={'display': 'grid', 
        'grid-gap': '30px',
        'grid-template-columns': 'repeat(auto-fit, 300px)',
        'justify-content': 'center',
        'width':'100%'}),

    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),

    html.Div([
            html.H3(children='Campaings performance'),

            dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_table.columns],
            data=df_table.to_dict('records'),
        )  
        ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br()

    
    ], className="container")
```

Готовые данные для дашборда я беру sql запросом ,  при этом нужно фильтровать данные меняя sql запрос (в примере меняется только диапазон дат , в результирующей таблице дат нет) .

Возможно ли с помощью callback функций или иным образом передать значения из inputов в переменные start_date , end_date и динамически обновлять дашборд ? Или хотя бы сделать форму на отдельной странице, через которую можно ввести даты и передать в sql запрос?
Благодарю за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Не пробовал такое, но как мне кажется вы можете засунуть целиком запрос в callback функцию, она будет взаимодействовать с клиентом посредством форм. Основное - это прописать чтобы ваша callback функция раздавала данные дальше - по всему дашборду, т.е. будет цепная реакция